# How can I remove index.php using Codeigniter on XAMPP?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, indexing, routes, xampp

I can't hide Codeigniter index.php on XAMPP 1.7.3

**URL:**

```
http://localhost/Servidor/agentesRainbow/index.php/agentes/tony
```

***tony*** is an argument

**My actual .htaccess:**

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /Servidor/agentesRainbow/

        #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Servidor/agentesRainbow/index.php/$1 [L]

        #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
        #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
        #request to index.php
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

        #This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
       RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|public|)
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Servidor/agentesRainbow/index.php/$1 [L]
        </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
        # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
        ErrorDocument 404 /application/errors/404.php
    </IfModule>
```

**My routes.php:**

```
$route['agentes/(:any)'] = "agentes/index/$1";

$route['default_controller'] = "agentes";
$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";
```

**My config.php:**

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/Servidor/agentesRainbow/";
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
```

**On httpd.conf:**

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /Servidor/agentesRainbow/>
         Options FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Order deny,allow
         Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this line to the  REQUEST_FILENAME conditions:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Servidor/agentesRainbow/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Here is the updated .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /Servidor/agentesRainbow/

    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Servidor/agentesRainbow/index.php/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Servidor/agentesRainbow/index.php/$1 [L]

    #This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|public)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Servidor/agentesRainbow/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 /application/errors/404.php
</IfModule>
```

Hope it solves your problem!

Answer (score 2):

I think the bar at the end of the rewrite condition is causing a problem. At least it broke the rewriting for me.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|public|)
```

Try removing the bar.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|public)
```

Comment: He doesn't even need that line as the two conditions above it will sort that.

Answer (score 0):

base_url should be just "http://localhost";

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|other|directories|you|want|accessible|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```