# Didn't remove index.php when redirection - codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

I tried many ways to remove index.php in my project. 
here's ways

here is my route file

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'auth/login';
$route['signin'] = 'auth/login';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

this is my htacess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

In config file

```
<Directory "C:/xampp2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Still index.php needed. what can i do for remove this ?

Answer (score 0):

in your config,

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

replace to :

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so     This one enabled

Comment: found text  #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so and remove # then save, restart you apache

Comment: actually it's going well, but try this on file .htaccess:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: please chek this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552166/how-can-i-remove-index-php-using-codeigniter-on-xampp)

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess file i create this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project_name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and it works for me.